# float not working on div

Tags: html, css, css-float

[image]I gave float Left to this div but its not moving left to its above div.....

the welcome and mail id should be adjacent to company logo div....

each div should be horizontally aligned

http://jsfiddle.net/TdcRJ/7/

```
 <div style="float: left;">
                        <p>welcome xyz! xyz@defie.co</p>
                    </div>
providing my code below

<div style="
    display: inline-block;
">
                    <a class="brand" href="&lt;?= HOME_URL ;?&gt;" style="">
                    Company LOGO
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: left;">
                    <p>47657 Lakeview Blvd</p>
                    <p>Fremont CA 94538</p>
                    <p>510-657-8981</p>
                </div>

                <div style="float: left;">
                    <p>welcome xyz! xyz@defie.co</p>
                </div>

                <div class="inline" style="padding-top: 12px;">

                        <ul class="homePageLists" style="">
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #333;">
                                <a style="color: #333;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                  <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_menu.png">
                                   Menu
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #; ">
                                <a style="color: #653921;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                  <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_inventory.png">
                                  Inventory
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #653921; ">
                                <a style="color: #653921;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                  <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_inventory.png">
                                  BOM List
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #653921; ">
                                <a style="color: #653921;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                    <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_inventory.png">
                                    Sub BOM List
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #9e1c20; ">
                                <a style="color: #9e1c20;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                    <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_product.png">
                                    Product
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #ff5100; ">
                                <a style="color: #ff5100;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                    <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_customer.png">
                                    Customer List
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #184179;">
                                <a style="color: #ff5100;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                    <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_vender.png">
                                    Vendor List
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

Comment: Can you be more clear?, can you name the divs and its arrangement? put style in CSS portion given in jsfiddle.

Comment: may be a rough figure of expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have to arrange div by div. Provide a float left for each div. And also set a heigh and with for each div. After that include this div inside another master div. I will include the jsfiddle soon

Comment: waiting for ur fiddle i am confused

Comment: yeah but can u tel the problem in the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width of your nav bar , then it will come left to top div

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <div class="companyLogo" style="width: 1009px;">
    <div style="width: 400px;height: 120px;">
    <div style="float:right;margin-top: -8px;">
    <a class="brand" href="&lt;?= HOME_URL ;?&gt;" style="">
        Company LOGO
        </a>

    <div style="clear: left;">
    <p>47657 Lakeview Blvd</p>
    <p>Fremont CA 94538</p>
    <p>510-657-8981</p>
    </div></div>

    <div style="float: left;">
    <p>welcome xyz! xyz@defie.co</p>
    </div>
    </div>
   <div class="inline" style="padding-top: 12px;">

    <ul class="homePageLists" style="">
     <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #333;">
     <a style="color: #333;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
   <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_menu.png">
                                       Menu
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #; ">
                                    <a style="color: #653921;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                      <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_inventory.png">
                                      Inventory
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #653921; ">
                                    <a style="color: #653921;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                      <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_inventory.png">
                                      BOM List
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #653921; ">
                                    <a style="color: #653921;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                        <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_inventory.png">
                                        Sub BOM List
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #9e1c20; ">
                                    <a style="color: #9e1c20;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                        <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_product.png">
                                        Product
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #ff5100; ">
                                    <a style="color: #ff5100;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                        <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_customer.png">
                                        Customer List
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #184179;">
                                    <a style="color: #ff5100;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                        <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_vender.png">
                                        Vendor List
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

                    <div>
                        <p>ABC Systems</p>
                        <p>1234 lakeview Blvd</p>
                        <p>CA 94538</p>
                        <p>510-657-8981</p>
                    </div>


                </div>
```